# Naming and switching windows

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, alfred

Let's say I want to dynamically assign an open **window** a number (or an alias) to be able to **activate** it quickly later.

For example, say that I manually activate a Chrome Window that contains several Amazon searches, and I want to assign it the number `1`, so that I can later activate it with a keyboard shortcut e.g. <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Similarly I may have another Chrome window holding a different set of tabs (e.g. StackOverflow tabs), and assign it the number `2`, so that I can later activate it by doing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. And so on.

A variant of the above would be using **aliases** (i.e. strings) that I could type on a lightweight prompt on the screen (as in Alfred or Spotlight), instead of using just numbers, to activate the corresponding window. An example here could be that I give a window the alias "foo", another window the alias "bar" and then I can activate them by typing `"w bar"` or `"w bar"` in e.g. **Alfred**. Obviously Alfred here is just an example. The goal is to just be able to give windows names and activate them later.

I know there are several automation / keyboard frameworks out there (e.g. Automator, Keyboard Maestro, and also obviously AppleScript), but many of these solutions don't seem to directly provide this functionality, and/or require extensive custom coding, making it almost as difficult as building a custom application from scratch for this particular purpose. Instead, I'm wondering if there's anything particularly well suited or readily available for this type of operation.

Comment: The trouble with trying to number windows is that the numbers change. Also, the window name is the name of the frontmost tab. I'd be tempted to use different browsers for each task, pinned to different Spaces. Then you can easily key-command the Spaces, which will retain their numbers so long as you set it up correctly.

Comment: @Tetsujin What numbers are you thinking of that change during a window’s lifetime ?  It’s z-index will change, sure, but all windows in macOS are assigned an id number that persists until the window is destroyed (I’m using “window” in its most general sense, so including tabs, the desktop, the menu bar, etc.).  **Amelio**: I think your objective is perfectly achievable using AppleScript or JXA in tandem with Alfred.  The script would write out to and read in from a file it would use to maintain a record or mapping that links your chosen alias to a specific window/tab.